# How do I get the number input to show up as a 2-digit number?

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm trying to let users pick an hour and minute combination in my HTML form. But I would like them to always show up as 2-digit values, not 1-digit, so that (for example) 9:05 AM comes up as `09` and `05` instead of just `9` and `5`.

I haven't found any attributes that deal specifically with this problem. I have found a `pattern` attribute, but it doesn't seem to do anything on Firefox 38 or Chromium 34, and the same goes for setting the `minlength` attribute to 2 (which I guess was only meant for strings, but I gave it a shot).

I do understand that the pattern I've tried in this example, `[0-9]{2}`, would only limit (a string) to 2 digits if it container more than 2 digits. Which is why I tried setting the value of my input field to `100` to test if the `pattern` attribute even works, but as I said, it made no change unfortunately. Maybe the `pattern` also only works for strings.

And since the `type` of the input element is `number`, Angularjs doesn't let me write `05` as a string in there. So I guess the solution should probably be through HTML5 attributes.

So, how would I get the values to show up as 2-digit numbers?

My form looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
            <h4>Hour</h4>
            <input type="number" 
                    max="23"
                    min="00"
                    step="1"
                    minlength="2"
                    pattern="[0-9]{2}"
                    class="form-control dialog-control" 
                    ng-model="hour"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
            <h4>Minute</h4>
            <input type="number" 
                    max="59"
                    min="00"
                    minlength="2"
                    step="1"
                    pattern="[0-9]{2}"
                    class="form-control dialog-control" 
                    ng-model="minute"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to restricting typing number more than 2 digits.

Comment: What about a list populated with the number options? I think most browsers will let you type and it will set the value in the list.

Comment: don't use type=number